# Allow scrolling beyond bottom of page

Tags: html, css, href, user-experience

I'm using ids links for headings like this

```
<h2 id="section-name">section x</h2>
```

and have links that jump the scroll down to them like this:

```
<a href=#section-name>section x</a>
```

The problem (in my view) is that when the page is shorter than the browser window height, or the heading is near the bottom of the page then the jump links have no effect because there's no scroll available to the browser.

I'd like the scroll to work, and just have my footer colour extended downwards as necessary.

The only way I can think of to do this is to have a massive `padding-bottom: 200em;` on the footer, but then it's easy to scroll into the nothingness and I have to guess how tall the user's screen is.

Is there a better way?

---

Here's the thing I'm working on http://demo.schemaexplorer.io/tables/Genre?GenreId=2&_rowLimit=100#data - note the `#data` on the end of the url, but notice it doesn't put the "data" heading at the top of the browser window.

Comment: This has always been a thing AFAIK. I don't think there's a way around this without increasing the document length.

Comment: You can only bring elements into the viewport relative to the height of the document. If the document has all elements in the viewport there's nothing really to scroll to. You could fix your footer to bottom:0 of the viewport and add the padding like you're saying or dynamically add some other spacing contingency but as it stands it's working as expected.

Comment: please look to some css features like overscroll-behavior you can have/control bounce effect this is maximum you can do with scroll area/view

Comment: I don't think overscroll is quite what I was after https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior but thanks, it's useful to know about.

Answer (score 2):

My modest advise is to use section highlighting by click.

By clicking a link get section id and highlight it with some class.

Use transitions to make it smoother.

```js
$('a').click(function() { 
 
  var currentSection = $(this).attr('href');
  $(currentSection).addClass('highlighted');

  setTimeout(function() {
      $(currentSection).removeClass('highlighted');
  }, 2000);
  
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}

.highlighted {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#section1">Section 1</a>

<a href="#section2">Section 2</a>

<div>
some text
</div>
<div id="section1">
section1
</div>

<div id="section2">
section2
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! That certainly draws the eye to the thing it jumped to.